# Hint on solving an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to solve the following integral
$$\int \dfrac{(\sqrt{a^2- x^2}) ^7}{(b x + c\sqrt{a^2 - x^2})^2} dx, $$
where $a, b,  c\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\} $.

**My attempt:**

Let $x=a\sin \alpha$ then $$\sqrt{a^2- x^2}= a \cos \alpha$$ and $$dx = a \cos \alpha d\alpha$$ and then the above integral is written as follows
$$a^6\int \dfrac{\cos^8 \alpha}{(b\sin \alpha + c \cos \alpha)^2} d\alpha. $$

I don't know in the following.  I will appreciate for any  help.

Comment: Hint: multiply top and bottom by $\sec^2\alpha$, take $t=\tan\alpha$, and use partial fractions.

Comment: Hi.  
I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean,
Can you explain easily for me?

Comment: $$\frac{\cos^8\alpha d\alpha}{(b\sin\alpha+c\cos\alpha)^2}=\frac{\cos^6\alpha d\alpha}{(b\tan\alpha+c)^2}=\frac{dt}{(t^2+1)^4(bt+c)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Hi.  Now how can i decompose this integral to partial fractions?

Comment: I'd suggest decomposing $\frac{1}{(t^2+1)^2(bt+c)}$ (which is already tedious enough), squaring, then doing some more decomposing. Some [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) tools will help, but are liable to unnecessarily introduce complex numbers (e.g. [WA does](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+1%2F%28%28t%5E2%2B1%29%5E2%28bt%2Bc%29%29+as+partial+fractions&dataset=)); powers of $t^2+1$ in denominators are fine here.

Comment: [Euler sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) is another route that leads to an antiderivative via partial fractions, but the PFs are much messier.